# How do I configure easy_install to use the right Python interpreter?

Tags: macos, mac, bash, python, easy-install

I am using mac OSX and have installed python 2.7.9 via [this article](http://wolfpaulus.com/jounal/mac/installing_python_osx/),

from `/usr/bin` if I run the command `ls -l /usr/bin/python*` in a bash terminal, I get

```
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  67 Jan 24 02:12 /usr/bin/python -> /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  74 Jan 24 02:12 /usr/bin/python-config -> /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python-config
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  75 Oct 19 16:39 /usr/bin/python2.6 -> ../../System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/bin/python2.6
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  82 Oct 19 16:39 /usr/bin/python2.6-config -> ../../System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/bin/python2.6-config
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  75 Oct 19 16:39 /usr/bin/python2.7 -> ../../System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python2.7
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  82 Oct 19 16:39 /usr/bin/python2.7-config -> ../../System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python2.7-config
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  68 Jan 24 02:12 /usr/bin/pythonw -> /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/pythonw
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  76 Oct 19 16:39 /usr/bin/pythonw2.6 -> ../../System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/bin/pythonw2.6
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  76 Oct 19 16:39 /usr/bin/pythonw2.7 -> ../../System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/pythonw2.7
```

If I run `ls -l | grep easy_install`, I get

```
-rwxr-xr-x   2 root   wheel       925 Sep  9 19:31 easy_install
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root   wheel       454 Sep  9 19:31 easy_install-2.6
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root   wheel       461 Sep  9 19:31 easy_install-2.7
```

And when I look at the shebangs for each of these 3 files they are respectively

```
#!/usr/bin/python
#!/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python
#!/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python
```

I have tried chmod-ing the write permissions so I can go in there and change the paths myself, but am still told by an alert in my IDE that I don't have write permissions when I do so. I also feel like I could be messing with files that might harm my system if I don't have them configured the right way. Could somebody tell me how to set up easy install so that it will work properly when I run a command like `sudo easy_install six`? Right now when I run this it is telling me

```
unable to execute /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/easy_install: No such file or directory
```

I have cd'd into that directory and changed the `easy_install2.7` file that lives there to simply `easy_install`, but I still get the same error. I have also tried copying the `easy_install` file from /usr/bin to that location with no luck:

```
python version 2.7.9 can't run /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/easy_install.  Try the alternative(s):

/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/easy_install (uses python 2.7)
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/easy_install-2.7 (uses python 2.7)
```

I have since returned all of the files to their original names and removed the `/usr/bin` version of easy_install from the 2.7 directory. Could somebody please help me out here?

**Other important information:**

1. I am trying to set up a local Cassandra cluster using [ccm](https://github.com/pcmanus/ccm) which is why I need to install these Python libraries
2. I installed Cassandra via [this link](http://christopher-batey.blogspot.com/2013/05/installing-cassandra-on-mac-os-x.html). In this article they have me install the latest python via homebrew, so my problem could be due to having alternative installations of Python on my system. I know this is a nono but decided to do it because I didn't feel comfortable copying my homebrew files into my System folder.

Answer (score 0):

Neither the Homebrew or python.org python installs change anything in the system directories.

They both put python into /usr/local/bin and this is what should be on your path before /usr/bin to allow you tp run python from the command line.

easy_install should be installed using this python and will put easy_install in /usr/local.bin wot the correct header.

Comment: I just went to /usr/bin and found easy_install, easy_install-2.6, and easy_install-2.7. I changed the names so that 2.7 is now just easy_install and it runs, but gives me a distribution not found error on the library. Is this the right approach??

Comment: No - never touch anything in system directories - see /usr/local./bin and install easy_install from that python

Comment: Ok, I'll change the names back now. I Is there a short list for which directories are "system" land which are for changing?

Comment: I should also mention that the first thing the Python.org article told me to do was execute this: 'sudo rm -R /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7', which I did. I did however follow all of the steps after that too.

Comment: That article is not from python.org and so is not the official doc - and deleting that path is wrong as it breaks any Apple an possibly third party code that uses python - that delete does explain your error message as you have broken Apple's python which all the files min /usr/bin run

Comment: Ok, you are right. I don't know why I thought that was python.org. what should I do, now? Please don't say reinstall macOS.

Comment: I would restore from your backup: ) Actually in this case do as I say in the answer and use the /usr/local/bin python

Comment: Ok my path shows /usr/local/bin before /usr/bin but how do I do the install that you mentioned?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue:

```
    Dhruv’s MacBook Pro:~ dhruv$ sudo easy_install pip
Password:
sudo: unable to execute /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/easy_install: No such file or directory
```

And I followed the same tutorial mentioned. How do I use a python from a particular directory, if that is what you are saying?

Comment: I actually ended up reinstalling Yosemite so that the old version of Python with proper symlinks was restored and then installed 2.7 in usr/local/bin, isolated from my system files. If you haven't deleted anything yet, then I would suggest just making sure  you have the right files and that your symlinks are pointing to the right places.

Comment: This is an overview of symlinks and how to make and destroy them: https://kb.iu.edu/d/abbe